# Duplicate classes when building app with firebase-firestore and google-cloud-language - android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting duplicate class errors when I try to build android app that use firebase-firestore and google-cloud-language.

> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.15.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.15.0)
>
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.15.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.15.0)
>
> Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice$Builder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.15.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.15.0)
>
> Duplicate class com.google.api.AdviceOrBuilder found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.15.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.15.0)
>
> ...
>
> Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeOfDayProto found in modules classes.jar (com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types:16.0.1) and proto-google-common-protos-1.15.0.jar (com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.15.0)

My build.gradle looks like follow:

```
...

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'

    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.19.0'
    implementation'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.76.0'
}
```

How can I solve the issuse ?

Comment: Did you made it work? if you did please do let me know how.

Comment: @SproutinGeek No I didn't. I migrate to firebase realtime database which doesn't have common dependency with google-cloud-language.